# Setting up configure.ac to enable asprintf() on EL5, needs _GNU_SOURCE

Tags: c, linux, autoconf, rhel5

What is the correct proper way to use autoconf to enable use of `asprintf` and `strndupa` on EL5?

Currently I have this in my configure.ac:

```
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([asprintf strndupa],,
   AC_DEFINE([_GNU_SOURCE], [], [Linux requires _GNU_SOURCE for asprintf]))
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([asprintf strndupa uname],, AC_MSG_ERROR([some needed function(s) not found]))
```

But autoconf is caching the test the negative test results so the second `AC_CHECK_FUNCS` fails.

I can exclude `asprintf` and `strndupa` from the second test, but then if defining `_GNU_SOURCE` doesn't work we will not know of the failure until make fails. What is the proper way to use these new GNU extensions in autoconf?

Comment: Can't you just unconditionally define `_GNU_SOURCE` up front?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a very clean solution, but would probably work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the macro `AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS` before doing any checks that require `_GNU_SOURCE`.

Comment: Good idea, but `AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS` is not supported on EL5.

Comment: You probably need to install a newer version of Autoconf.